# How to edit parent form controls in my child forms designer

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I have a baseview form which I added a grid. I have another view form that inherits my base view form. I would like to edit this grid in my derived class designer. I set the access modifier in my base view form to protected but this does not help.

Comment: Most of the .NET 2.0 controls have designers that do not work in a derived form.  No simple workaround for this.

Comment: What version of .NET/Visual studio are you using? This works on from .NET 4/VS 2010.

Comment: I'm using .net 4 vs 2010. I'm having no luck. It works with some of my base classes but not with others. When I hover over the controls I see a lock on the left hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do it. It's a nightmare waiting to happen. Look the other way for five minutes and it will be eight levels deeps and sprawling across your entire application.

Abstract out the common behaviours in to classes, controls etc.